# Select Count Query Giving Inaccurate Results

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query the table CANCELLATION_DEFINITION, and count the amount of rows that have an ACTION_TYPE value that isn't "-". Unfortunately, the query is giving me inaccurate results. For example, it returns 3 for this table when there are 6 rows in the table that have an ACTION_TYPE value other than "-". Code is below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM    (
     SELECT DISTINCT 
     ACTION_TYPE
     FROM CANCELLATION_DEFINITION WHERE ACTION_TYPE != '-'
     )AS distinctified
```

Comment: You are counting the number of distinct rows where the action type is the same and it doesn't equal '-'. If there are 2 rows where it = `othervale` for example this will only be counted one.

Comment: How is C# relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM    (
     SELECT ACTION_TYPE
     FROM CANCELLATION_DEFINITION WHERE ACTION_TYPE != '-'
     )AS distinctified
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You could try adding some explanation and even simplifying the query.  However, the answer doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

When you perform a select distinct, it only returns distinct (ie different) values. So if you have action_type ["INSERT", "UPDATE", "UPDATE", "DELETE"] it will only give you 3 results because it merges UPDATE and UPDATE.

What you really want is

```
SELECT COUNT(ACTION_TYPE) 
FROM CANCELLATION_DEFINITION 
WHERE ACTION_TYPE != '-'
```

Comment: +1 . . . This is a much better answer than the accepted answer and was even first.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The OP actually had tagged this question originally with C# but it was edited out by other users, so I assume he might have been relying on the ability to use adapter.Fill[dataSet, "distinctified"] which I didn't provide in my answer. Unfortunately I don't think distinct does what OP thinks it does, and SQL lessons are outside the scope of this Q&A format :).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the distinct keyword and changed your query to:-

```
SELECT COUNT(ACTION_TYPE)
FROM CANCELLATION_DEFINITION WHERE ACTION_TYPE != '-';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below, I don't believe there is a need for your sub query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ACTION_TYPE) AS distinctified
FROM 
CANCELLATION_DEFINITION
WHERE ACTION_TYPE != "-"
```

Comment: The as keyword will not come here after single query.

Comment: Good call, forgot to remove it from the original copy + paste.